# How to add a string to multiple string for printing external

Tags: vb.net, string, pdf, for-loop, arraylist

This is going to be a long one, but easy fix.

So i've manage to convert a pdf to string, then able to print an external pdf simply by putting the name of the file in a textbox.

I've also figured how to extract certain text from the pdf string, now the certain text are also files located in an external location (I use c:\temp\ for testing).

Which leaves me with one problem, the text I extract, I use shellexecute to print, works fine if its one string. however, If the file name I extract is more than one it will count it as a single string, thus adding the location and .pdf to that one string. instead of the two or more strings. which will do something like this:

As you can see, it will send that to the printer. I want to send one at a time to the printer. like this:

I've tried using an Arraylist and various methods. but my own lack of knowledge, I cannot figure it out.

I'm thinking a "for loop" will help me out. any ideas?
Below is my code.

```
        Dim pdffilename As String = Nothing
        pdffilename = RawTextbox.Text
        Dim filepath = "c:\temp\" & RawTextbox.Text & ".pdf"
        Dim thetext As String
        thetext = GetTextFromPDF(filepath)        ' converts pdf to text from a function I didnt show.

        Dim re As New Regex("[\t ](?<w>((asm)|(asy)|(717)|(ssm)|(715)|(818))[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled)               ' This filters out and extract certain keywords from the PDF

        Dim Lines() As String = {thetext}
        Dim words As New List(Of String)
        For Each s As String In Lines
            Dim mc As MatchCollection = re.Matches(s)
            For Each m As Match In mc
                words.Add(m.Groups("w").Value)
            Next
            RawRich4.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray)
        Next
        'This is where I need help with the code. how to have "words" putout  "c:\temp\" & RawRich4.Text & ".pdf" with each keyword name

        Dim rawtoprint As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray)
        Dim defname As String = Nothing
        defname = RawRich4.Text
        rawtoprint = "c:\temp\" & RawRich4.Text & ".pdf"

        Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        psi.UseShellExecute = True
        psi.Verb = "print"
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
        psi.FileName = (rawtoprint) ' this is where the error occurs it doesn't  send both files separately to the printer, it tries to send it as one name
        MessageBox.Show(rawtoprint) ' This is just to test the output, this will be removed. 
        'Process.Start(psi)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a known pattern for file names? Say they all are 8 chars or start with a string like ASM, for example? Also, if your input file name is 1 file, how come you are getting many file names?

Answer (score 0):

Updated.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Program
Sub Main()      
    Dim pdffilename As String = RawTextbox.Text
    Dim filepath = "c:\temp\" & RawTextbox.Text & ".pdf"
    Dim thetext As String
    thetext = GetTextFromPDF(filepath)        ' converts pdf to text from a function I didnt show.
    'thetext = "Random text here and everywhere ASM00200207 1 1 same here bah boom 12303 doh hel232 ASM00200208 1 2 "

    Dim pattern As String = "(?i)[\t ](?<w>((asm)|(asy)|(717)|(ssm)|(715)|(818))[a-z0-9]*)[\t ]"

    For Each m As Match In rgx.Matches(thetext, pattern)
        'Console.WriteLine("C:\temp\" & Trim(m.ToString) & ".pdf")
        RawPrintFunction("C:\temp\" & Trim(m.ToString) & ".pdf")
    Next

End Sub

Function RawPrintFunction(ByVal rawtoprint As String) As Integer
    Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.UseShellExecute = True
    psi.Verb = "print"
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
    MessageBox.Show(rawtoprint) This will be removed, this is just for testing to see what files will be printed
    'Process.Start(psi) This will be uncomment.
    return 0
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I will give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: I step through the program and the code fails where you tell me to put rawprintfunction after the rawrich4 text....etc

This is what I did, don't know if this is correct.
`RawRich4.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray) = RawPrintFunction("c:\temp\" & RawRich4.Text & ".pdf")`
I get this error during step.
Conversion from string "ASM00200207
ASM00200208" to type 'Double' is not valid. 
also getting this: _Warning 1 Function 'RawPrintFunction' doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a 'Return' statement?_

Comment: Sure, but its just text from a PDF,  imagine you copy everything from a PDF and paste it into richtextbox. however, only selectable text are extracted. and the code above extract certain text based on keywords defined in the Regex.

_Random text here and everywhere ASM00200207 1 1_
_same here bah boom 12303 doh hel232 ASM00200208 1 2_

Comment: I made the regular expression case insensitive and used a for each loop to process the string from your function.  It will output the file string.  You may have to do a bit of re-coding for the print function, since I didn't check it.

Comment: Thank you Tim, your code worked fine. perfect :), with minor changes.
`Function RawPrintFunction(ByVal rawtoprint As String) As Integer
        Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        psi.UseShellExecute = True
        psi.Verb = "print"
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
        psi.FileName = (rawtoprint)
        Process.Start(psi) ' This will be uncomment.
        Return 0
    End Function`

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand the code -*since I can't test and run it here*- you can iterate through file names stored in `words` variable and send it to printer. Following is an example on how to do that :

```
....
....
Dim Lines() As String = {thetext}
Dim words As New List(Of String)
For Each s As String In Lines
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = re.Matches(s)
    For Each m As Match In mc
        words.Add(m.Groups("w").Value)
    Next
    RawRich4.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, words.ToArray)
Next

For Each fileName As String In words
    Dim rawtoprint As String 
    rawtoprint = "c:\temp\" & fileName & ".pdf"

    Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.UseShellExecute = True
    psi.Verb = "print"
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.Arguments = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString()
    psi.FileName = (rawtoprint) ' this is where the error occurs it doesn't  send both files separately to the printer, it tries to send it as one name
    MessageBox.Show(rawtoprint) ' This is just to test the output, this will be removed. 
    'Process.Start(psi)
Next
```